# datetime excluding weekend in django

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have an problem regarding my datetime,I need a date excluding weekend for last 15 days,I am solving this issue but I got all the date including weekends.
Here is my code:-

```
days_to_show = 15
    start_date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_show)
    #print start_date
    query = Book.objects.values('startdate').order_by('timeid') \
           .annotate(spent=Sum('spent')) \
           .filter(project_id=project_id,
                   startdate__range=(start_date, datetime.datetime.now()))

    spent_dict = dict((d['startdate'], d['spent']) for d in query)
    date_list = [str((start_date) + (datetime.timedelta(days=day)))
                             for day in range(0, days_to_show)]


    sp_data['time'] = [{'startdate': date, "spent":spent_dict.get(str(date),0)}
                             for date in date_list ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Create `date_list` in two phases:

```
# get all dates for the period
date_list = [(start_date) + datetime.timedelta(days=day)
                         for day in range(0, days_to_show)]
# filter out week ends
date_list = [str(date) for date in date_list if date.weekday() not in (5,6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python side (slower, because data is pulled to the app, then filtered)

If, as the op's comment mentions, the dates are stored as `VARCHAR` instead of `DATE` or `DATETIME` in the database (bad idea), you can use Python to convert them to a `date` or `datetime` python time, then use `.weekday()` on python `datetime` and `date` objects to filter out Saturday (5) and Sunday (6), e.g.

```
without_weekends = [book for book in books if book.date.weekday() not in [5, 6]]
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

### Database side (better, the data is stored as DATE/DATETIME, and filtering happens DB-side, so only relevant data is sent back to the app)

Django has a `week_day` lookup that works on date/datetime types: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day

> but I got all the date including weekends

You can exclude weekends from the range you want, e.g. do `Book.objects.filter(...).exclude(date__week_day__in=[1, 7])` to remove Sunday (1) and Saturday (7) from the queryset

Comment: in database i am stroring startdate as a varchar not a datetime.

Comment: It's a bad idea to do `__range=(a, b)` on a `VARCHAR` type instead of a `DATETIME` type I think, but I updated with a Python solution